# How to quickly find which Activity in AWS Step Function State Machine fails with CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I checked this guide [AWS CLI For Step Functions](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/stepfunctions/index.html#cli-aws-stepfunctions), but it only describe about an State Machine's execution is passing or not, but no way to know which exact Activity fails and which exact Activity passes, is there a quick way to find that out?

The UI of Step Function has that visually showing which exact Activity fails, but not with the CLI.

Answer (score 2):

You asked which exact Activity fails, but based on your question I think you are looking to find which state in your state machine fails.

In AWS console, Step Functions visually showing which exact State fails based on the data from **Execution History**.
To do it from CLI you can use **get-execution-history** command like this:

```
aws stepfunctions get-execution-history --execution-arn <execution-arn> --reverse-order --max-items 2
```

**--reverse-order** Lists events in descending order of their timeStamp, and is useful because the fail events are the last events in execution history.

**--max-items** Used because the last event is for ExecutionFailed event and the events before that is for state Fail event. You can increase it to see more events.

Comment: Thanks, but that's only getting the State Machine's execution history, and if a State Machine has 10 different steps (each with an Activity), some passes, some fails, how do I know which step is failing and which step is passing.

Comment: Unless you have some retry or try catch, then failing step is the last step in execution history.

Comment: If you want to get all failing states including ones that eventually passes because of retry or error handling, then you need to get all execution history and filter events with fails. That's exactly what is happening in Step Functions detail page.

Comment: I tried `get-execution-history` , it only shows the error, but didn't show which Activity is causing it. But I see it in the AWS UI, it seems the CLI does not provide this.

Comment: The name of state is not in the same event, so you need to get the name from prevous event (TaskStateEntered)
Here is an example of result from get-execution-history:
```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "type": "LambdaFunctionFailed",
        },
...
        {
            "timestamp": 1603835138.469,
            "type": "TaskStateEntered",
            "id": 2,
            "previousEventId": 0,
            "stateEnteredEventDetails": {
                "name": "HelloWorld",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Got it, wish the CLI can provide similar UX as the UI. And how do we generate that workflow chart in PNG  from the given State Machine definition?